# Импорт векторных изображений в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svg

Загрузил несколько иконок типа SVG в папку drawable. Подсвечивает красным и не используются. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конвертировать в VectorDrawable?

Comment: Попытаться импортировать через [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#running).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы загрузить SVG картинку вы должны сначала щёлкнуть правой кнопкой мыши по папке drawable затем навести на "New" и в выпадающем меню нажать "Vector Asset". Появится такое окошко в нём нажмите на "Local fle (SVG, PSD)" и в строке "path" введите путь до вашего SVG файла затем нажмите "Next" и на последнюю кнопку "Finish". Не пугайтесь что вместо SVG файла создался "xml" файл так и должно быть.